# Does this curve have any nonzero rational points?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Consider the equation $ x^4 -t^{2}x - t = 0 $, where $x$ and $t$ are real and $t$ is fixed. Does this equation have any other rational solutions apart from $(x, t) = (0,0)$ ?

Partial solution: Let $ f(x) = x^4 - t^{2}x - t $ and assume that $f(x) \geq 0$. Therefore, if $f(x) = 0$ we have a minimum. Differentiating $f$ w.r.t $x$ and equating to zero we arrive at $4x^3 = t^2$. Hence, any rational solution must satisfy $x = u^6$ for some rational $u$.

Comment: I presume you mean $x$ and $t$ are rational ?

Comment: Yes @ Yves, real and rational, though the former may be "trivial"

Comment: What is contradictory ?

Comment: I think it would be nice if you can demonstrate the ''triviality'' with a solution.

Comment: Your values yield $\phi^2 - \phi - 1 = 0$, which doesn't have any rational solution ! Please, next time, take your time before commenting let alone downvoting unnecessarily !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34066/discussion-between-isaac-and-yves-daoust).