# Rational points on $4x^5 + y^2 = z^2$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Does the title curve have any nonzero rational points ?

I have to admit that i didn't find any significant insight to this problem.

Comment: Yes. $(x,y,z)=(0,\pm t,\pm t)$.

Comment: Thanks @mathlove, maybe i should edit the question so that it asks for $nonzero$ rational solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be missing something simple here, but:

$$z^2-y^2=4x^5 \Rightarrow (z-y)(z+y)=4x^5$$

Now, let $s,r$ be any rational numbers with $r \neq 0$. Then the system
$$
z-y= r\\
z+y = \frac{4s^5}{r}
$$
has unique solution
$$z=\frac{r^2+4s^5}{2r} \\
y=\frac{4s^5-r^2}{2r}$$

Which leads to the rational points:
$$(s, \frac{4s^5-r^2}{2r}, \frac{r^2+4s^5}{2r})$$

Comment: Thanks @N.S !, i also kindly request for your opinion on this question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1605390/300579